# how can I get key from firebase real-database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database

[image: firebase database]

I read key "20160877" to update type this is easy because there is one key.
by this way ==>

```
                table_user.child("20160877").child("type").setValue("2");
```

If I put many keys like "20160877" and have value inside it and want to update type in all type in all keys how can I did this?

I tried this way **but it create new key** then update type in it, I want to update the existing data and not create new data

```
DatabaseReference table_user;
FirebaseDatabase database;
String id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_main);

     database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     table_user = database.getReference("Users");

}

public void current_member(View view) {
    table_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            id =snapshot.getKey();
            table_user.child(id).child("type").setValue("1");
            Toast.makeText(AdminMainActivity.this, "تم تفعيل صفحة الاعضاء الحاليون", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

public void active_C_page(View view) {

    table_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            id =snapshot.getKey();
            table_user.child(id).child("type").setValue("2");
            Toast.makeText(AdminMainActivity.this, "تم تفعيل صفحة الترشح", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: firebase fanout approach can help when you want to update multiple  row in firebase.

Comment: What do you mean by "but if I put many keys I want read all keys and update type"?

Comment: if there is many key like "20160877" and have "type" how can I update "type" in all this keys,

Comment: how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the status of all users, you'll need to loop over the user nodes in the `snapshot` in your `onDataChange`.

So something like:

```
table_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            id = userSnapshot.getKey();
            table_user.child(id).child("type").setValue("1");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Or you can directly get the reference from the `userSnapshot`

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        userSnapshot.getReference().child("type").setValue("1");
    }
}
```